# Measurabilty of a function

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $k:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function, where $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\nu)$ are finite measure spaces. Further let $g: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive and measurable function. Suppose
for each $x\in X$ we can find a non-negative $s$ such that
$\int_{Y}(|(k(x,y)|\wedge s\ ) d\nu(y) =g(x)$. Here $a\wedge b$ is the minimum of the values $a$ and $b$.
Define now $s(x):=\inf\{s\geq 0| \int_{Y}|k(x,y)|\wedge s=g(x)\} $.
Is $s$ measurable?

Comment: maybe since the integral with respect to $s$ is increasing, could be a help?